# MySQLi SSL connection stops working after php 7 upgrade

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli, upgrade, php-7

I have a strange issue when moving my project from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7, I have a database class which allows you to set an SSL connection to the database after calling `mysqli_init();` and before calling `mysqli_real_connect()`.

I have been developing this on PHP 5.6 and have successfully created a SSL connection to a remote server and all working great, the remote database server does NOT use a self signed certificate.

In the `setSSL` method of my db class I have this:

```
        if($verify) { $this->mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true); }
        $this->mysqli->ssl_set($key, $cert, $ca, $capath, $ciphers);
```

The method sets `$verify` to a default setting of `true` and left as is, the certificate bundle is passed through the variable `$ca`.

This has been working great on PHP 5.6 and doing exactly what it should be and confirmed that the connection is indeed using an SSL connection.

On the same server I created a sub domain and set it to use PHP 7 (I hear performance is much better and my code is PHP 7 friendly).

I done a complete copy of my code on the new sub domain and everything works fine, except for the remote SSL mysqli connection.

I have checked the removed features in PHP 7 and many other things but can't find out why this is happening.

Extracts from logs:

> [Msg: mysqli::real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed]
>
> [Msg: mysqli::real_connect(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL]
>
> [Msg: mysqli::real_connect(): [2002] (trying to connect via
>   tcp://******.co.uk:3306)]

On another note, this is the same error produced when I was first developing this feature on PHP 5.6 if I didn't pass the ca certificate bundles over.

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @neuhaus I have updated the question with extracts from the log. As stated above, this works fine in 5.6 but breaks on PHP 7. I have confirmed that the correct location for the ca file is being passed to the ssl_set method.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure this is because you are using a chained certificate (which is common) and MySQL currently [does not support chained certificates](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54158) (which is annoying).

You normally **do not** load the intermediate certificate into the client certificate pool, as this is lowering security and a very common mistake many webserver owners do.
But as there is no other solution concerning MySQL, you might want to do just 
that.

So as a workaround, try loading the CA **and** all intermediate certs into your certificate pool of PHP - keeping in mind this is bad practice.

**Update:**

I think the bug got resolved long ago but MySQL Team didn't update their ticket, ... depending which ssl library is baked into your MySQL (usually openssl) it should already work.

Read here how to concatenate and build a proper certificate chain: [How to chain a SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997559/how-to-chain-a-ssl-certificate)

Comment: Thank you @DanFromGermany for your reply, I understand what you're saying and will try what you suggested but still not sure why this is happening. The ca bundle I have in the app and the full file location is passed to the ssl_set option. The thing is, I am connecting to a remote db server that has had no changes, the connection works fine on my dev server running PHP 5.6, but stops working on PHP 7 connecting to the same remote server. The ca bundle is from Mozilla's repository and updated by cron job automatically.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and no affect, still getting the exact same error.

Comment: The chain/bundle must be sent by the server. It should not be stored permanently on a client. If it works on the old client but not with the new, it sounds exactly the same as if the server sends the wrong intermediate certificate. **Can you please verify your certificate chain using** `openssl verify <your_cert.pem>` **command.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance @DanFromGermany, appreciated. I have verified the ca bundle and got a simple 'OK' from the command line. The PHP 5.6 and PHP 7 dev areas are on the same server using the same ca bundle and the same full path to it. On the new sub-domain, if I downgrade the domain to use PHP 5.6 the same code works, put back to PHP 7 it stops working . I have plesk and can change the PHP version in the control panel.

Comment: Maybe the path to the certificates went away. Compare the output of this with the two PHP versions: `print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());`

Comment: Sorry fro the delay @DanFromGermany, run that on both versions and are identical. Must admit, I am quite baffled here.

Comment: I have seen a difference between the versions, the PHP 5.6 version use the libmysql for mysqli, while on my server PHP 7 uses the native driver mysqlnd. I read online that the native driver does not support SSL connections??? I will verify more but also read that the native driver is now default, surprised they would do this without SSL support.

Comment: Reading mixed things online about whether mysqlnd supports SSL or not for my versions of PHP.

Comment: The error you're getting would imply it does support SSL/TLS.